# Submitting magento 2 module to market place

Tags: magento2, module

I have developed a custom shipping module for Magento 2 and have submitted in https://developer.magento.com portal.

My component got approval after business approval after 3 days and now its status have changed to 'v.1.0.0 - Approved after Business Review'

Its been 3 days but I did not get any responses after that.

What I should do after this?

Comment: I think you should directly contact. It's not relevant to here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check below URL for How to submit a Magento 2 extension to the market place

http://www.magenerds.com/2016/05/03/how-to-submit-a-magento-2-extension-to-the-market-place-2/